# Matlab's vectorized sprintf like function in python

Tags: python, matlab, printf

After using Matlab for some time I grew quite fond of its `sprintf` function, which is vectorized (**vectorization** is the crucial part of the question).

Assuming one has a list`li=[1,2,3,4,5,6]`,

```
sprintf("%d %d %d\n", li)
```

would apply the format on the elements in `li` one after another returning

```
"1 2 3\n4 5 6\n"
```

as string.

My current solution does not strike as very pythonic:

```
def my_sprintf(formatstr, args):

    #number of arguments for format string:
    n=formatstr.count('%')

    res=""

    #if there are k*n+m elements in the list, leave the last m out
    for i in range(n,len(args)+1,n):
        res+=formatstr%tuple(args[i-n:i])

    return res
```

What would be the usual/better way of doing it in python?

Would it be possible, without explicitly eliciting the number of expected parameters from the format string (`n=formatstr.count('%')` feels like a hack)?

PS: For the sake of simplicity one could assume, that the number of elements in the list is a multiple of number of arguments in the format string.

Comment: Do you have to use a format string?

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham: No, the newer version with string.format() is also fine.

Comment: If you wanted a robust solution I would be inclined to encapsulate the logic in a class, subclass ing string.Formatter

Answer (score 3):

You could use a variation of the [grouper recipe](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes)  if you get the user to pass in the chunk size.

```
def sprintf(iterable,fmt, n):
    args = zip(*[iter(iterable)] * n)
    return "".join([fmt % t for t in args])
```

Output:

```
In [144]: sprintf(li,"%.2f %.2f %d\n", 3)
Out[144]: '1.00 2.00 3\n4.00 5.00 6\n'

In [145]: sprintf(li,"%d %d %d\n", 3)
Out[145]: '1 2 3\n4 5 6\n'
```

You could handle when the chunk size was not a multiple of the list size using izip_longest and str.format but it would not let you specify the types without erroring :

```
from itertools import izip_longest


def sprintf(iterable, fmt, n, fillvalue=""):
    args = izip_longest(*[iter(iterable)] * n, fillvalue=fillvalue)
    return "".join([fmt.format(*t) for t in args])
```

If you split the placeholders or get the user to pass an iterable of placeholders you could catch all the potential issues.

```
 def sprintf(iterable, fmt, sep=" "):
    obj = object()
    args = izip_longest(*[iter(iterable)] * len(fmt), fillvalue=obj)
    return "".join(["{sep}".join([f % i for f, i in zip(fmt, t) if i is not obj]).format(sep=sep) + "\n"
                    for t in args])
```

Demo:

```
In [165]: sprintf(li, ["%.2f", "%d", "%.2f", "%2.f"])
Out[165]: '1.00 2 3.00  4\n5.00 6\n'

In [166]: sprintf(li, ["%d", "%d", "%d"])
Out[166]: '1 2 3\n4 5 6\n'

In [167]: sprintf(li, ["%f", "%f", "%.4f"])
Out[167]: '1.000000 2.000000 3.0000\n4.000000 5.000000 6.0000\n'

In [168]: sprintf(li, ["%.2f", "%d", "%.2f", "%2.f"])
Out[168]: '1.00 2 3.00  4\n5.00 6\n'
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to remove the `+=` in the for loop. The following version is approximately three times faster than yours. It also works even in cases where you want to print the `%` symbol in the output. Therefore, the format string contains `'%%'`.

```
def my_sprintf(format_str, li):

    n = format_str.count('%') - 2*format_str.count('%%')
    repeats = len(li)//n

    return (format_str*repeats) % tuple(li[:repeats*n])
```

A less hacky way is possible if you use the newer `.format` method instead of `%`. In such a case, you can use the `string.Formatter().parse()` method to get the list of fields used in the `format_str`.

The function then looks like this:

```
import string

li = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
format_str = '{:d} {:d} {:d}\n'


def my_sprintf(format_str, li):

    formatter = string.Formatter()
    n = len(list(filter(lambda a: a[2] is not None, 
                        formatter.parse(format_str))))

    repeats = len(li)//n
    return (format_str*repeats).format(*li[:repeats*n])
```